# Table causing "cause cycles or multiple cascade paths" error but I can't see why, please asist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5, code-first

When I try to use CodeFirst to create my database I get the error

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Location_dbo.Section_SectionID' on table 'Location' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Looking at the two tables I do not see why this error would be poping up, can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Section Table:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace FFInfo.DAL
{
    [Table("Section")]
    public class Section
    {
        [Required, Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Int16 ID { get; set; }

        public Int64? LogoFileID {get;set;}

        [Required, MaxLength(250), Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
        public string RouteName { get; set; }

        [Required, MaxLength(15), Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("LogoFileID")]
        public virtual File Logo { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<SectionTranslation> Translations { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Location Table:

```
    using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace FFInfo.DAL
{
    [Table("Location")]
    public class Location
    {
        [Required, Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Int16 SectionID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public byte LocationTypeID { get; set; }

        public Int64? MapID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("SectionID")]
        public virtual Section Section { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("LocationTypeID")]
        public virtual LocationType LocationType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

LocationTranslation:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace FFInfo.DAL
{
    [Table("LocationTypeTranslation")]
    public class LocationTypeTranslation
    {
        [Required, Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public byte TypeID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public byte CultureCodeID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("TypeID")]
        public virtual LocationType Type { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CultureCodeID")]
        public virtual CultureCode CultureCode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

SectionTranslation:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace FFInfo.DAL
{
    [Table("SectionTranslation")]
    public class SectionTranslation
    {
        [Required, Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Int16 SectionID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public byte CultureCodeID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string Synopsis { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("SectionID")]
        public Section Section { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CultureCodeID")]
        public virtual CultureCode CultureCode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

CultureCode:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace FFInfo.DAL
{
    [Table("CultureCode")]
    public class CultureCode
    {
        [Required, Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public byte ID { get; set; }

        [Required, MaxLength(5), Column(TypeName = "char")]
        public string Code { get; set; }

        [Required, MaxLength(50), Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
        public string LanguageName { get; set; }

        [Required, MaxLength(50)]
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about the `LocationType` entity? Does it have a required reference to `Section`? That would be the reason for the exception.

Comment: The `LocationType` entity only contains `ID` and `Name` fields. No reference to `Section`

Comment: OK, and does the `SectionTranslation` entity contain a collection of `Location`s?

Comment: No it does not. The `XXXTranslation` files contain a reference to the root entity (i.e. `SectionTranslation` references `Section`), a reference to `CultureCodes` entity and then any extra columns needed for text strings that would need to be translated into different fields. And as a note, there should be a `virtual ICollection<>` in the `Location` entity that references `LocationTranslation`

Comment: Do the `XXXTranslation` classes have a common base entity? Sorry, to ask these annoying questions but the problem with this multiple cascade path exception is always that the reason is not (alone) in the two entities that the exception is talking about but can be in some other entities that are connected with those entities in the class graph. I would definitely help if you could show more classes that are related with `Section` and `Location`.

Comment: What do you mean by base entity? I will add a few more entities to the OP in a few.

Comment: I meant a class that all `XXXTranslation` classes inherit from. But that's apparently not the case. Are there more relationships/entities in the model? I still don't see multiple delete paths.

Comment: No there is no master class, I believe there are around 75 or so total entities in this DataModel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to find multiple cascading delete paths in your model, but I couldn't. Based on the snippets in your question and additional remarks in the comments the class graph seems to look like below. The meaning of the lines/arrows is the following:

- Every line is a relationship with FK constraint in the database. The arrow points in the direction from principal to dependent of the relationship.
- Solid line: Required relationship (= FK not nullable). At the same time (by EF mapping conventions) it means that such a solid arrow indicates cascading delete in the arrow direction (unless you have overwritten cascading delete with Fluent API which I assume you haven't)
- Dashed line: Optional relationship (= FK is nullable). At the same time (by EF mapping conventions) it means that such a dashed arrow is not associated with cascading delete (unless you have overwritten this default with Fluent API which I assume you haven't)

[image: Multiple Cascade Paths]

The exception basically means: *There is an entity X and an entity Y such that there is more than one path along solid arrows from X to Y and the arrow from `Section` to `Location` is part of one of the paths.* (The exception refers only to this arrow because "introducing this FOREIGN KEY constraint" apparently closed a second path from some X to some Y.)

I cannot find such an X and Y in the graph above (which probably means that the graph is incomplete, i.e. there are more relevant entities/relationships, or that I overlooked something). I also can't see cycles.

You could of course just try to break the solid line that the exception is refering to by disabling cascading delete:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Location>()
    .HasRequired(l => l.Section)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(l => l.SectionID)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

(Alternative: Make `Location.SectionID` nullable of type `Int16?`.)

From business viewpoint this might not be the best choice, but in order to have any other choice it is necessary to find the two conflicting paths.

Comment: Thanks, I could not find anything either which is why I posted. There must just be something we are not seeing and at this point I don't think you want to dig though all 75 of my entities. I have already disabled the Cascade Delete so I could progress. Appreciate the time.